# Reduce the size of SNMP4J

Tags: java, snmp4j

I want to trim SNMP4J to maximum for using with my application.
Currently the jar has 457KB and SNMP4J agent has 522KB. By trimming the unwanted features , how can I reduce the size? I would like to remove the TCP support hence the packets are UDP. Similarly which all features can be trimmed?

Answer (score 2):

Find the source of the jar file, remove the unwanted classes and files and create jar.
size of the jar files can be reduced through this way.

Comment: can u please specify which class to be removed and which features are to be removed

Comment: classes that are not used in your application.